# Spliting Validation message and adding to a PopUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootbox

I have a validation summary on my ASP.NET page.  It is hidden on screen as I want to inject the contents of the validation summary into a popup box.  So I can get the text of the validation summary as below:

```
var str = $('#myValidationSummary').text();
```

If I alert that str with two fields in error I would get something like the below returned:

```
First Name is required.Surname is required.
```

So I want to do a split on full stop as each of my error messages end with a .

```
var result = str.split(".");
```

which then returns below:

```
First Name is required,Surname is required,
```

I am using bootstrap in my website so I am using bootbox library to create an alert like:

```
bootbox.alert('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>Cannot Save as there are errors');
```

So I create an alert with the generic Cannot Save message displayed beside a warning icon - however what is the best way to add each individual error message that may be in the validation summary which has been split - I would like the error message to still end with full stop which has been replaced with a , on spliting.  And have a line break after each error message and perhaps start with a bullet point

Doing the below just concantenates the error messages to be header generic message

```
bootbox.alert('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>Cannot Save as there are errors' + result);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to have your messages as html?

Comment: do you mean here - var str = $('#myValidationSummary').text(); call var str = $('#myValidationSummary').html(); instead?

Comment: using .html() works fine - Thanks :) - if you want to add that as an answer Ill mark as accepted